# Offering a trial version of a PHP application, easier alternatives to ioncube, zendguard & c.?

Tags: php, licensing, obfuscation, time-trial

I developed and distributed a trial version of a PHP software I sell.
I used ioncube to encode the PHP source and check the installation date online. It works pretty well but the problem is that most of the users who downloaded the trial don't even install it, probably because they realize they need to edit php.ini and copy the ioncube loader somewhere in their computers.

Almost all the similar questions on stackoverflow advise ioncube, zend or similar solution...could you advise a simpler (from the point of view of the user) solution?
I don't care if it is less secure than ioncube, I'm ok if it works and prevent cracking for most of the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe users are just not interested in proprietary software?

Comment: Why not sell hosted solution ???

Comment: @hakre Just the trial version is encrypted, and users know it before downloading; so I'm quite sure the reason is that it requires work (which is not trivial for some users) for installation.

Comment: @baba because it is not what I want to do, I want to concentrate my effort on the developing of the software and not on the hosting issues.

Comment: @Eugenio: Offer installation support.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a scripting language, and it can be quite easy to decode (and disable the trial functionality)

What you could try is hosting it on a demo server, granting access to that for a limited time, and then later revoke access when the trial period is over

Comment: An on-line demo is already available but I'm sure (according to the messages I receive) that some people want to download the application and try it in their machines.